# "Local" publish-subscriber pattern for use in MVC wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, observer-pattern, publish-subscribe

Using wxpython in MVC, I looked for a way to let the models tell the controllers about changes. I found (py)pubsub, which implements a global notification mechanism: Messages are sent to one place (the pubsub Publisher), which sends them to all subscribers. Each subscriber checks whether the message is interesting, and does what is needed.

From Smalltalk times, I know a more "local" approach: Each model object keeps a list of interested controllers, and only sends change notifications to these. No global publisher is involved. This can be implemented as part of the Model class, and works in much the same way, except it's local to the model and the controller.

Now is there a reason to use the global approach (which seems much less performant to me, and might be prone to all the issues related to global approaches)? Is there another package implementing a local observer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really seeing the subtle difference here. As far as I know, pubsub is the way to go. It's included in wxPython in wx.lin.pubsub or you can download it from http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/. You can put the listeners just in the models and the publisher(s) just in the controller or however you need to. Here are a couple links to get you started:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around for a while to do MVC with wxpython and i know what you mean about pubsub being global.

The latest idea i've come up with is each view and model have there own observer.
The observers have weak references to their handlers and it all works in a separate thread so as to not block the GUI. To call back to the GUI thread I'm using wxAnyThread Gui method decorator.

There are 3 types of signal that get sent, for the model you can set which attributes are observed they automatically send out a signal when they are changed. then on both the model and the view you can send a message signal or a keyword signal. Each of the three signal types have to be unique per view or model as they are used to make a tuple that identify them.

**model attributes**

controller handlers are decorated with

```
@onAttr('attributeName')
def onModelAttributeName(self, attributeName)
```

When you bind to a method that handlers attributes it straight away calls the handler with its current value and then continues to observe changes.

**Sending messages**

Use the method

```
view/model.notify('Your message'):
```

The controller callback is decorated with

```
@onNotify('Your message')
def onYourMessage(self):
```

**Sending keywords**

Use the method

```
view/model.notifyKw(valid=True, value='this)
```

The controller callback is decorated with

```
@onNotifyKw('valid', 'value')
def onValidValueKw(self, valid, value)
```

The GUI is left knowing nothing about the models the only thing you add to the GUI is the view signaler, the controller attaches it self to this, so if you don't add a controller the view will just happily fire off messages to no one.

I've uploaded what i have so far on github

https://github.com/Yoriz/Y_Signal

https://github.com/Yoriz/Y_Mvc

Both have unit test which should give a bit of an example of what it does, but i will create some wxpython examples.

I'm using python version 2.7 and the Ysignals module requires
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures/2.1.3 for the threading.
Please take a look ill be interested in what someone else thinks of this way of approaching mvc or to point out something i seriously overlooked.